# Can using epoxy with a Bluetooth RF change the frequency?

Tags: rf, antenna

My device is a Bluetooth beacon.  It will work placed on a metallic part.  What epoxy can I use that prevents the metal underneath the antenna from affecting the RF?

---

how can prevent the ground plane to shift the frequency?
[image]

Comment: I doubt epoxy has any effect on it. If the metal part is affecting the signal, no epoxy will fix it.

Comment: yeah I know the metal underneath is impacting in RF performance but I need something that can prevent the metal affect the RF

Comment: @Sussy - Hi, Please stop using the text box at the bottom of the page for adding new information. It is labeled "Your Answer" and would be used by *other people* to answer your question. You should add new info / diagrams etc. by making an [Edit] to the question (I did that for you). You can reply to someone's comment (which doesn't add new information requiring an edit) by writing a comment yourself (not an answer). This difference between answers & comments is one of the ways that Stack Exchange differs from typical internet forums. Please read the [tour] and [help] to see more site rules.

Comment: What you need is distance between them.

Comment: the PCB has like 1 cm between PCB and metal.

Comment: Can you adjust the antenna to work with the metal plane?

Answer (score 0):

> what Epoxy can I use that helps the Rf don't get affected by the metal underneath the antenna?

What you want is impossible – you can't "hide" the metal plane with a coating.

Comment: While I don't think it's a matter of selecting an "Epoxy", there are microwave absorbent materials, that if placed between the antenna and the metal plate, might reduce the detuning of the antenna (and I think that is OP's question, though not expressed as such). But I agree, he's barking up the wrong tree and should get help to redesign or retune the antenna to work in the environment required.